# Calculating boxplots with imputed data

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation, boxplot, mice

I have imputed a dataset which has over 200 variables, and 20 observations. 
In worst case, 80% of the data is missing, in the best case 100% is available. 5 out of the 20 participants provided data for all the variables.
Participants were aksed to rate the importance of 13 variables under a certain circumstance, from 0 to 25.

I imputed this using `mice(imp=25, max_it=25)`, and got a nice dataset after a few hours.
I'm now analysing it using boxplots per circumstance (thus 13 boxplots at a time), but wonder how I should do this.

From a Dutch textbook, I understood that you do the tests for each imputation, and then average the results. 
Does that mean that I should calculate the data for each variable/imputation, and then divide by 25? It seems a bit crude...

I also wonder how much it differs for these descriptive statistics...

Comment: Boxplots typically contain quantile-based measures (medians, quartiles etc...). Multiple imputation doesn't provide rules to create one "combined dataset" but rather a "combined estimate" (for the median, quartiles etc.). So in order to draw a box-plot, you have to calculate the medians, quartiles etc. for every imputed dataset and take the average of these. The "combined" median, quartiles etc. can then be used to construct the box-plot you want. Sounds difficult, yes, but MI is not intended to make nice plots.